# Perforce P4 client: how can I transfer my workspaces and bookmarks to a new computer

Tags: perforce, migration

I have many client-specs and workspaces defined for many different Perforce servers. 
I got a new computer and installed P4V client, but I can't see any of my client-specs because they
are all specific to the old computer. Is there any way to migrate this information without laboriously 
re-creating each client-spec and workspace on the new system?
I use the UI, not the command-line interface.

Comment: Did you install just the P4 command-line client or P4V as well?

Answer (score 15):

Workspaces

The 'host' field in the workspace limits its use to that computer. Changing the host field to blank or more preferably the name of the new computer will allow it to be used on the new computer, however you must also either:

1. copy all the data from the old root to the same directory on the new computer, assuming you wish to use the same root path, or
2. perform a forced full sync

doing this ensures the workspace is in sync with the server.

To do this, click the 'workspace' icon (picture of a terminal screen), click the cancel filter icon to view all workspaces (top right of the panel, a cross over a funnel). 
Right click on the desired workspace and select 'edit workspace' and change the host field (in advanced tab) to the name of the new computer, or clear the host field. After doing this, the 'switch to workspace' option will appear on the context menu.

To find the name of the new computer select 'create a new workspace' from Connection menu and note the name of the 'host' field and then cancel the menu.

Bookmarks

P4V does not have an easy method for transferring bookmarks, however bookmarks are stored in bookmarks.xml found in a directory:

```
C:\Users\loginname\.p4qt\nnnnClients\
```

If you only have one directory called '0001Clients' you're in luck, but you may have more than one of these directories so it may require searching for the right bookmarks.xml file. Once you find the right one, transfer it to the new computer which is likely to only have one of these directories and the bookmarks will appear after reloading the client.

Comment: The editing workspace procedure also works if you have changed the hostname of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

**Bookmarks**

Craig is correct, but here's a way to find the right xxxxClients directory both on the source and the target computer (you might very well have several of them on the target computer as well).

Look in `connectionmap.xml` in `C:\Users\loginname\.p4qt` and search for you user name. It will give you the xxxx number and the directory where you can find (source) and then overwrite (target) the existing `bookmarks.xml`.

(Reloading the client was not necessary for me - the bookmarks showed up right away.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I didnt change computers or workspaces at all.
So I was curious why I had the same issue.

Turns out I re-named my PC at some point, so to fix it there was two solutions:

1: re-name the PC back to what it was before

2: In the workspaces tab in the P4 client, right click your workspace, edit it, hit the advanced tab and change the 'Host' to your computer name.

If you don't know your PC name, just type 'View your PC name' into the start menu.

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

The steps presented in [Craig’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/521680/150988#522836) will work if you are migrating from Windows to Windows. 
But if your new computer is a MacBook, then the new location is
‌`/Users/<User ID>/Library/Preferences/com.perforce.p4v`.